# How can I make output of sed command as variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

How can I make the below command as variable ? I mean I need to assign this command to variable to use it within for loop.

```
for i in $(sed 's|/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/||' /home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/logs.csv )
```

I have file named start with the below path:

```
/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log
```

I need to remove all this

Comment: Are you trying to modify the *path* of the file, or the *content* of the file? What is the purpose of the loop? Please [edit] your question with more context.

Comment: Doesn't `sed 's|/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/||' /home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/logs.csv` remove "*/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/*" from lines in the file "/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/logs.csv"  ... Isn't that what you want ... Do you need it to actually edit that file instead of printing output to terminal?

Answer (score 0):

```
var1="$(for i in $(sed 's|/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/||' /home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/logs.csv ))"
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make output of `sed` command as variable?
>
> How can I make the below command as variable ? I mean I need to assign
> this command to variable to use it within for loop.
>
> ```
> for i in $(sed 's|/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/||' /home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/logs.csv )
> ```

Do you mean to read each output line to a variable in a loop? If so, then you can use [Bash's process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) with a `while` loop like so:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line
  do
    # Do whatever you want with the line
    echo "$line"
    done < <(sed 's|/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/||' /home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/logs.csv)
```

It also can be done by piping the output to the loop like so:

```bash
sed 's|/home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/||' /home/bssuser/Scripts/Amany/logs.csv |
while IFS= read -r line
  do
    # Do whatever you want with the line
    echo "$line"
    done
```